# flutter type cast to List<Map<String, String>>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable like this

```
  List<Map<String, String>> expense = [
    {
      "date": "01-03-2021",
      "person": "John",
    },
    {
      "date": "01-03-2021",
      "person": "John",
    }
    ];
```

and then

```
myVar = json.encode(myVar);
```

Now how do I get back to the same type variable as the start? I tried doing this, but could not

```
json.decode(myVar).toList().map((e) => e as Map<String, String>)?.toList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your type casting is done wrong, you should not call `toList()` on a `dynamic` type, also your `e as Map<String, String>` won't work as `e` is a `dynamic` type and Dart will not be able to infer the type of everything and so will not be able to perform the type casting properly. Here is how you can cast your JSON:

```dart
List<Map<String, String>> expense = [
  {
    "date": "01-03-2021",
    "person": "John",
  },
  {
    "date": "01-03-2021",
    "person": "John",
  }
];

final myVar = jsonEncode(expense);
final result = (jsonDecode(myVar) as Iterable)
    .map((e) => Map<String, String>.from(e))
    ?.toList();
```

**Output**:

```sh
MYVAR: [{"date":"01-03-2021","person":"John"},{"date":"01-03-2021","person":"John"}]
RESULT: [{date: 01-03-2021, person: John}, {date: 01-03-2021, person: John}]
```

[You can try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/1fab04184f7c4261cae2f5aa14be4357)